# send message to specific channel in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a variable which has a value like `<#637301291068031001>`
so in my case

```
welcomechID = <#637301291068031001>
```

then i try to send message to that id by

```
message.channel.get(`'${welcomechID}'`).send(`Welcome to the server, ${gdata.user.username}!`, attachment)
```

also tried both `message.channel` & `message.channels`

```
message.channel.get(parseInt(welcomechID)).send(`Welcome to the server, ${gdata.user.username}!`, attachment)
```

but all i get is Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: It seems like channel is undefind. Can you post the whole app? (The creation of client and etc)

Comment: yes other things works fine other than this event and 1 more event

Comment: Maybe try and watch this video. I think it will organize thing for you.

https://youtu.be/jQwmm7WiVqM

Comment: Im not sure why channel is undefind  but i need to see the whole app to tell. In what function do you call message.channel?

Comment: OMG its working when i changed from `message.channel` to `client.channel`

Comment: its in `guildmemberadd` event which has client `event.bind(null, client, db));` oh i get it message is not there XD thats why may be

Comment: Yes nice this is probably it. The message object in all the examples is an object of the event client.on(message => {}) that means you receive it from the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was issue with `message` but after changing it to `client` its working fine

```
client.channel.get(`'${welcomechID}'`).send(`Welcome to the server, ${gdata.user.username}!`, attachment)
```

Answer (score 0):

channel ID has **only** numeretic format, so you need use

```
let welcomeChannel = message.guild.channels.get('637301291068031001')

if(welcomeChannel) welcomeChannel(`Welcome to the server, ${gdata.user.username}!`)
```

Or if you want to attachImage you can use

```
let welcomeChannel = message.guild.channels.get('637301291068031001')

if(welcomeChannel) {
    let emed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setDescription('Welcome to the server, ${gdata.user.username}!')
        .setImage('ImageURL')
    welcomeChannel(embed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, turn on developer mode. (Tutorial on turning it on [here](https://discordia.me/en/developer-mode))

Then you right-click or tap and hold on mobile to copy the channel ID.

Then:

```
const abcd = client.channels.find('channelnamehere', channelName)
abcd.send("message here")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as a string not as Int and also remove the ' ' in `'${welcomechID}'` Javascript's template literals automatically converts it string. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
welcomechID = '637301291068031001'
message.channel.get(`${welcomechID}`).send(`Welcome to the server, ${gdata.user.username}!`, attachment)
```